# PyTorch memory explosion｜RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. How to troubleshoot the problem?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, artificial-intelligence

Sometimes, when PyTorch is running and the GPU memory is full, it will report an error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 916.00 MiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 4.47 GiB already allocated; 186.44 MiB free; 4.47 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 4.47 GiB already allocated; 186.44 MiB already allocated. 186.44 MiB free; 4.47 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Sometimes it may not be caused by the model size, so how to prob the problem step by step?

Tried with very small model but the problem still exists. How to solve it?

Comment: This has been asked and answered multiple times here, we do need another duplicate question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

So here I summarize how to solve this problem step by step.

1. Check whether the GPU memory is actually full. Possibly you have more than one GPU on your computer. In the terminal, enter `nvidia-smi`, then it shows the GPU information of your computer, normally be like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX A5000    Off  | 00000000:17:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 51%   67C    P2   111W / 230W |  23953MiB / 24564MiB |     68%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA RTX A5000    Off  | 00000000:65:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 60%   78C    P2   106W / 230W |  18372MiB / 24564MiB |     27%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     13291      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13998      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20176      C   python                           7977MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20407      C   python                           7977MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20693      C   python                           7977MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     25065      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     25369      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     13291      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 15MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     13386      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              108MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     13998      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                194MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     14085      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               82MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     14979      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            6MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     19570      C   python                           1849MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     20200      G   gnome-control-center               27MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     20830      C   python                           7977MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     23158      C   python                           7977MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     25065      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 39MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     25090      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               12MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     25369      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 16MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     25455      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               58MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

A better way to dynamically track memory usage is `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi`, this command would refresh the GPU status every 1s. Here we can see 2 cards, and the memory usage is 23953MiB / 24564MiB in the first GPU, which is almost full, and 18372MiB / 24564MiB in the second CPU, which still has some space.

2. So as the second GPU still has some space, why the program still show `RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory.`? Firstly you should make sure that when you run your code, the memory usage is smaller than the free space on GPU. For example, my program only takes 2000MiB, so theoretically, it can be put on the second GPU. In this case, the error may indicate you have put your program to the default(first) GPU. Solution is to specify the program to use the second card in the command line:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1  python main.py
```

3. If the first and second steps are done, it can be a problem of your code. My idea of debugging is to comment out part of the code at a time, and then use the command `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi` to see if there is any memory explosion, to locate the code that caused the memory explosion. There are many different kinds of code problems, so let's take some common examples.

3.1 batch_size is too big. When it comes to checking the code, the first thing to do is to look at the `batch_size`, but if the batch_size is too big it should not be able to run even for one epoch, because something will go wrong during or even before the forward propagation. So if the code can't even complete one forward propagation, you should first check the batch_size.

3.2 The optimizer doesn't step, which will cause the memory to explode only after the training has run some iteration, and if the `optimizer.step()` line is missing, the gradient will keep accumulating and the memory will not be released.

3.3 Doing arithmetic on a cuda tensor with a constant. This case also usually leads to memory explosion after running some iteration. This error is usually reported by torch, but there are also very subtle cases, such as constants that don't specify which device they are on, and need to be discovered manually. The result you get is actually on cuda, for example:

```
>>> a = torch.Tensor(1).cuda()  
    # BTW, if you want to assign 1 to a, you should do : a = torch.Tensor([1]).cuda() instead of a = torch.Tensor(1).cuda(). The latter one is wrong.
>>> a == 1
tensor([False], device='cuda:0')
```

The result should be handled properly at this time! If the resulting tensor is not assigned to a variable, it may stay in the memory and not be released. I usually move it directly to the CPU for arithmetic.

3.4 The case when you need to save some cuda tensor. This situation usually leads to a relatively large GPU memory usage, which may lead to memory explosion. For example:

```
 outs = [out.cpu() for out in outs]
 all_outs = torch.cat([all_outs.cpu(),torch.stack(outs).cpu()],dim=1)
```

In this case, I've already moved every tensor in the list of outs to the cpu, but it still takes up a lot of memory. Because this is the code at inference time, I don't need its gradient subsequently, the solution is to detach the gradient:

```
outs = [out.detach().cpu() for out in outs]
all_outs = torch.cat([all_outs.cpu(),torch.stack(outs).cpu()],dim=1)
```

This way it doesn't take up any GPU memory.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the few best practices you can try to figure out exact solution:

1. Reduce Batch Size:
   If you are using a batched data input, try reducing the batch size. A smaller
   batch size will require less GPU memory.
2. Simplify the Model:
   If possible, simplify your model architecture resulting into reducing the
   number of layers, parameters and fits within the memory constraints of your
   GPU.

3.Free Up GPU Memory:
Before training your model, make sure to clear the GPU memory.

```
import torch
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

4.Mixed Precision Training Approach:
You can use mixed precision training to reduce the memory requirements like
use float16 instead of float64. The *torch.cuda.amp* will take care and
enhance the automatic mixed precision training.

Ultimately, the exact solution depends on your specific model and data, so you may need to experiment with different approaches to find the best compromise between model complexity and available GPU memory.